# Get apk file icon, name and size in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

is there any way to get Android system installed apk file icon, name and size in D7 and obviously Adb commands to uninstall the selected apk from the android system for rooted or non-rooted devices

Comment: You seem to be somewhat confused.. D7 doesn't do Android.

Comment: D7 cannot create Android apps, but it can shell out to ADB to send commands.

Comment: I don't need to create apps in D7 but need to shell adb commands to get the system installed apps list , size and their icons .. is possible ??

Comment: Your question is very poorly phrased, hence the lack of answers. Executing a new process is routine. Call CreateProcess.

Comment: Read the [ADB documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). It tells you exactly which commands are supported. To get information about an APK, you probably have to use the `adb shell pm list packages -f <PACKAGE>` command, or the `adb shell pm path <PACKAGE>` and `adb pull <remote> <local>` commands and then parse the APK yourself. To uninstall an APK, use the `adb shell pm uninstall [options] <PACKAGE>` command.